# Silverlight. Writable bitmap. Makes bad images from still video. Is there a workaround?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have code like this:

```
            MediaElement me = myPlayer.MediaElement;
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(me.NaturalVideoWidth, me.NaturalVideoHeight);
            wb.Render(me, null);
```

I want make thumbnails from video in run-time. It works fine with one little quirk. When video in the media element is paused the bitmap image comes broken. Like a corrupted jpeg. Sometime it is black square with some random coloured dots...

I think it is Silverlight bug. My question - **is there a workaround?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried taking a snapshot of the entire client area of your app to see if there is a difference?  I have a hunch that there is a device-dependent issue with taking snap of just the MediaElement.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I found what is wrong. And I wonder why nobody said that in their "brilliant" blogs? I gather - knowledge became so cheap that it is now cheap knowledge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By very chance I found what is wrong... I googled the solution above, verified it with several blogs and silverlight.net forums. I spent 40 min reading all those community giants publications trying to find what could be wrong in 3 lines of code. Everything pointed that this should work. And it does work.. Sometime...

However when I try to make picture of still media element it **doesnt work 9 times out of 10**..

the solution is dead simple.

```
        MediaElement me = myPlayer.MediaElement;
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(me.NaturalVideoWidth, me.NaturalVideoHeight);
        wb.Render(me, null);
        image.Source = wb;
        **wb.Invalidate();**
```